# SQL Union and special sum

Tags: sql, postgresql, sum, union, distinct

I'm new to SQL queries so hopes this question isn't stupid.

I got two tables like this:

Table 1:

| Name | Value | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| global | g | 1 |
| domain | x | 2 |
| domain | y | 1 |
| agg | ba | 1 |

Table 2:

| Name | Value | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| global | g | 1 |
| domain | z | 1 |
| agg | bb | 1 |

I need to get this kind of table - which is consist of all rows without duplications, and the global row should changed it's count to the sum of the 'domain' rows from the first table only:

Table 3:

| Name | Value | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| global | g | 3 |
| domain | x | 2 |
| domain | y | 1 |
| domain | z | 1 |
| agg | ba | 1 |
| agg | bb | 1 |

is this kind of operation is possible?

Comment: is the name for table 1 and 2 the same? Like table1.name = table2.name? You want to group by name or value?

Comment: yes it's the same, I want to union all rows, hope the example is clear

Comment: Is domain-z-2 correct in your example desired result? Or should it be domain-z-1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_15&fiddle=56637c13c1b654a2459aa9c02a64268a)

```
SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE "Name" <> 'global'    -- 1

UNION

SELECT                      -- 2
    'global', 
    'g',
    SUM("Count")
FROM table1
WHERE "Name" = 'domain'
 
UNION

SELECT * FROM table2
WHERE "Name" <> 'global'   -- 1
```

1. Union both tables without the `global` row
2. Create a new `global` row for the expected sum of the table1 `domain` records. Union it as well.

Comment: Thanks that was very clear!
I got another problem now, as the two table are actually queries, and the first line don't know about the table I made in the next lines from the query. any tricks?

Comment: You could run your query inside a WITH clause (so called CTE) and reference this instead the table directly: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_15&fiddle=622f6f271145f9c2ebf55e5315f5f794

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```
SELECT x.name, x.total_val, sum(occurence)
FROM (SELECT name, total_val, occurence FROM test union all select name, total_val, occurence from test2) x
group by x.name, x.total_val
```

You can check on this db fiddle as well [test case](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4VUVqTLy4PpVPWiZTNLpaP/1#&togetherjs=a18ufx0CpI)

Comment: AFAIK this would create a simple group for ALL names and values. But the TO states, he just want to group the counts of the domain records... And this result must appear not in a domain record itself but the global record.